# Generation of expressions in the form of division of one random int operand by a similar operand, the result of execution of which will be an int num

Tags: python

code:

```
import random
import re
numbuttons = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
class Task:
    def __init__(self, difficulty = 1):
        c = None
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        self.task = ""
        b = ""
        if difficulty == 1:
            self.task = random.choice(numbuttons[1:])
            self.target = self.task
        if difficulty == 2:
            self.task = random.choice(numbuttons[1:]) + random.choice(numbuttons)
            self.target = self.task
        else:
            self.task = f"{random.choice(numbuttons[1:])}"
            for i in range(difficulty - (difficulty - 8)):
                if i == 0:
                    a = random.choice(random.choice([numbuttons, operators]))
                elif i == (difficulty - (difficulty - 8)) - 1:
                    a = random.choice(numbuttons[1:])
                elif b in "^+-*/,√" and c != "/":
                    if b == "/":
                        c = b
                        numfordivide = int(re.split('[+\-*/]', self.task)[-2])
                        mult = 2
                        numbers = []
                        if numfordivide != 1:
                            while mult**2 <= numfordivide:
                                while numfordivide % mult == 0:
                                    numbers.append(mult)
                                    numfordivide = numfordivide / mult
                                mult = mult + 1
                            if numfordivide > 1:
                                numbers.append(numfordivide)
                            if numbers == []:
                                numbers.append(1)
                        else:
                            numbers.append(1)
                        a = str(random.choice(numbers))
                    else:
                        a = random.choice(numbuttons[1:])
                        c = None
                elif c == "/":
                    a = random.choice(operators)
                    c = None
                else:
                    a = random.choice(random.choice([numbuttons, operators]))
                b = a
                self.task = self.task + a
                b = a
the_task = Task(14)
print(the_task.task)
```

The program randomly generates strings like "21*2+4-9".
It is important to me that when the expression (this string) is executed, the result is an integer, as is the result of all operations within it. However, the program sometimes generates strings like "7+5-14/6" where, of course, the result is not an integer, although I have tried to avoid this. How to fix this?

Comment: Why `range(difficulty - (difficulty - 8))`? This is just `range(8)`

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this code is doing in more detail? The variable names `a`, `b`, `c` don't help to understand it, and there are no comments in your code.

Comment: variable a is the character that will be added to the string; the same character is written to variable b (`b = a`), but not to be added to the string, but to determine which character will be added next (for example, so that the "+" character is not followed by the "*" or "0" character); by using variable c I tried to prevent the problem mentioned in the question: when the "/" character is added to the string (which, so far, is the only operator that can lead to a non-integer result),

Comment: it is written to this variable, so that only one of the operators can be added to the string in the next iteration of the loop (so that the conditional "4/2" does not turn into "4/27").

Comment: I don't understand this. It looks like you are implementing rules that you have not described, and this is not just generating any random expression. I will leave it for someone else.

Comment: It just generates random expressions. All this is to prevent it from generating meaningless expressions/expressions with non-integer results.

Comment: What is `difficulty`?

Comment: This should be clear from the code. It defines the length of the expression.
You noticed correctly at the beginning that `range(difficulty - (difficulty - 8))` is the same as `just range(8)`: this is my mistake, I wanted to make it so that the length of the expression cannot be greater than 8. However, this issue was not and is not a priority for me anyway, and I don't think it is in any way relevant to the problem.

Comment: *"This should be clear from the code"*: if it was, I wouldn't have asked. Honestly, I don't understand this code. But maybe someone else can understand it. You would however increase the chances of a helpful response if you would do everything possible to clarify your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using brackets, you can simply change your algorithm, so that when the division operator is used, giving you a/b, you generate b and a/b to be integers, then a is simply the multiple of the 2. You can use the same approach for square roots

Comment: I don't get it...